# php my crawler crash after some time segmentation fault error

Tags: php, linux

i am a newbie in PHP and with my knownledge i build a script in PHP but after some time it crash.
I tested it on 5-6 different Linux OS, debian, ubuntu, redhat, fedora,etc. Only on fedora don't crash but after 3-4 h of working he stops and don't give me any error. The process still remain open, he don't crash, just stop of working, but this only on fedora.

Here's my script code:

```
<?

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$file = fopen("t.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $line = trim($line);
    $line = crawler($line);
}
fclose($file);

function crawler($line) {
    $site = $line;
    // Check target.
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; pt-pt) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27";
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$line);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<=300) {

        $check2 = $html = @file_get_html($site);
        if($check2 === false) {
            return $line;
        } else {
            foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
                $checkurl = parse_url($element->href);
                $checkline = parse_url($line);
                if(isset($checkurl['scheme'], $checkurl['host'])) {
                    if($checkurl['host'] !== $checkline['host']) {
                        $split = str_split($checkurl['host']);
                        $replacethis = ".";
                        $replacewith = "dot";

                        for($i=0;$i<count($split);$i++) {
                           if($split[$i] == $replacethis) {
                           $split[$i] = $replacewith;
                           }
                        }
                        chdir('C:\xampp\htdocs\_test\db');
                        foreach($split as $element2) {
                            if(!chdir($element2)) { mkdir($element2); chdir($element2); };
                        }
                        $save = fopen('results.txt', 'a'); $txt = "$line,$element->innertext\n"; fwrite($save,$txt); fclose($save);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

So my script crawl all backlinks from the targets i specified in t.txt, but only outgoing backlinks... then he scale on directories and save the information.

Here are the errors I got:

```
Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It seems somewhere is a bug.. something is wrong... any ideea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such error can be thrown when you haven't free memory. I believe it happens inside your simple_html_dom. You need to use

```
void clear ()   Clean up memory.
```

while using it in loop according to [its documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

Also you perform two http request for each line. But it's enough only one curl request. Just save responce

```
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

and than use `str_get_html($html)` instead of `file_get_html($site);`

also it's bad practice to use error suppression operator `@`. If it can throw an exception you better handle it by `try ... catch` construction.

Also you don't need to do such things

```
$site = $line;
```

just use `$line`

and finally instead of your long line `$save = fopen('results.txt', 'a');...............` you can use simple `file_put_contents()`

And i suggest you to output to console what you actually doing now. Like

```
echo "getting HTML from URL ".$line
echo "parsing text..."
```

so you can control process somehow

Comment: well... thanks... Like i say i am newbie and i don't know how to optimize the code... is clearly somewhere.. something is wrong... i will review every step you say :) Thanks again.